# UIImageView not rotating around centre but jumping all over the place

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I have got a test compass VC with the proverbial compass image (128 x 128) with central co-ords 128,160. When I rotate the iPhone the compass moves correctly BUT jumps all over the place.

I have tried inserting additional code out of paranoia to force it to stay within central bounds but doesn't appear to make any difference.

Any ideas?

EH

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading*)newHeading {
    if (newHeading.headingAccuracy > 0) {    
        self.currentHeading = newHeading;    
        self.trueHeadingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)newHeading.trueHeading];    
        self.magneticHeadingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)newHeading.magneticHeading];    
        float heading = -((newHeading.magneticHeading*M_PI)/180.0f);    

        // Additional code to force image starts here
        self.arrowImage.frame = CGRectMake(128,160,128,128);    
        self.arrowImage.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);    
        self.arrowImage.center = CGPointMake(160,160);   
        // Additional code to force image ends here

        self.arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(heading);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SORTED but this makes no sense. No anchor points, no layers used. All I did in the Size Inspector was change the width/height of the image to 1,1 rather than the true size of the image which is 128,128.

Comment: Addenda - for this to work you must change the View/Mode from Scale to Fill to Center.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried setting the anchor point of the view to it's center? this should result in rotating around the center and not around (0,0).
you can try some code like:

`[self layer].anchorPoint = CGPointMake(width/2, height/2);`

Comment: Was hoping that's what my line self.arrowImage.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5); was for. Uncertain how to apply the layer approach in this method.

Comment: CGPointMake(int x, int y) will create a point at the specified pixel coordinates. In your case this is CGPoint(0.5, 0.5), these are NOT percentage values.

Comment: Hmm I always thought this was a percentage. if I change this to (100, 100) it goes off the screen. Changing it to (0.50, 0.50) or (0.50f, 0.50f) makes no difference.

Comment: no these are definitely not percentage values. if you set the anchor to (100,100) that means that your rotation center will be x+100, y+100 from the upper left corner of your rotation body. (0.50,0.50) or (0.50f,0.50f) will, indeed, make no difference because this will just move the rotation center .5 pixels away form its default value. you have to use relational values form the top left corner of your rect for the anchor

Comment: Something odd is going on. If I use (0.50, 0.50) it jumps around the screen a little. If I use (160.0, 160.0) it vanishes completely.

Comment: SORTED but this makes no sense. No anchor points, no layers used. All I did in the Size Inspector was change the width/height to 1,1 rather than the true size of the image which is 128,128.